# LIMIT the rows inserted into a table based on the date and the max row count number listed for that date in another table in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have three tables. The my_db.threshold_table contains the maximum number of random records per day I want inserted into my_db.daily_table which will be dropped and recreated before the next day’s insert. The source table for cust_num is my_db.customer_table

How do I write this in Snowflake SQL?

(edit by me: Sorry can't figure out how to post a table in a stackoverflow question and have it display properly)

my_db.threshold_table

+-----------+-------+----------+
|  Run_DT   |       | Max_Rows |
+-----------+-------+----------+
| 8/22/2020 | 348   |          |
| 8/23/2020 | 418   |          |
| 8/24/2020 | 523   |          |
| 8/25/2020 | 653   |          |
| 8/26/2020 | 816   |          |
| 8/27/2020 | 1,021 |          |
| 8/28/2020 | 1,276 |          |
| 8/29/2020 | 1,595 |          |
| 8/30/2020 | 1,993 |          |
| 8/31/2020 | 2,492 |          |
| 9/1/2020  | 3,115 |          |
| 9/2/2020  | 3,893 |          |
+-----------+-------+----------+

my_db.daily_table

+----------+
| cust_num |
+----------+
| 1111     |
| 1222     |
| 1333     |
| 1444     |
| Etc.     |
+----------+

My_db.customer_table

+----------+
| cust_num |
+----------+
| 1111     |
| 2111     |
| 1222     |
| 1333     |
| 2222     |
| 1444     |
| 2333     |
| Etc.     |
+----------+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your situation permits you to have **multiple SQL statements** to achieve the result, then this approach should be simple and efficient:

```
SET MAX_ROWS = (SELECT IFNULL(ANY_VALUE(MAX_ROWS), 0) AS MAX_ROWS FROM (SELECT MAX_ROWS FROM MY_DB.THRESHOLD_TABLE WHERE RUN_DT < CURRENT_DATE()))
;
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO MY_DB.DAILY_TABLE (
  CUST_NUM
)
SELECT CUST_NUM
  FROM MY_DB.CUSTOMER_TABLE SAMPLE ($MAX_ROWS ROWS)
;
```

If you are required to do this in a **single SQL statement**, then you could use this approach instead:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO MY_DB.DAILY_TABLE (
  CUST_NUM
)
SELECT C.CUST_NUM
  FROM MY_DB.CUSTOMER_TABLE C
       CROSS JOIN MY_DB.THRESHOLD_TABLE T
 WHERE T.RUN_DT = CURRENT_DATE()
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RANDOM()) <= T.MAX_ROWS
;
```

Note: I have elected to use the INSERT OVERWRITE construct here, which is generally a much better practice than performing a drop + recreate of the target table each day. But you can decide whether or not this is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: @SteveMaritz: glad to hear that it was useful to you. Is there any particular reason that you have not "accepted" this answer?

Comment: Nope just did. Thanks again.